# Critical error when trying to retrieve text value of GTKEntry

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm learning the basics of GTK for a school project and I am trying to create a basic program which prints the value of a text entry as it is changed. Whilst I am getting an output of some kind, it is a critical error which says :

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
The text is : (null)
```

My code is as follows :

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "salesbase.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void change_text(GtkWidget *widget, GtkEntry *data){
    const char* output = gtk_entry_get_text(data);
    printf("The text is : %s\n", output);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GObject *window;
    GtkEntry *input;

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "ui/main.ui", NULL);

    window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainwindow");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    input = GTK_ENTRY(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "test_entry"));
    g_signal_connect(input, "changed", G_CALLBACK(change_text), &input);



    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't pass `&input` to `g_signal_connect()`; `input` is already a pointer, and thus `&input` is actually a pointer to a local variable, which you don't want to use as the object itself. Pass just `input` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth argument to [`g_signal_connect`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-data) is `gpointer`, which is alias to `void *`, so is is already a pointer. `input` is a pointer, so if you want to pass it, you can pass it directly:

```
g_signal_connect(input, "changed", G_CALLBACK(change_text), input);
```

Passing `&input` has two problems: it passes pointer-to-pointer (`GtkEntry**`) to function expecting pointer (`GtkEntry*`), which fails; and `input` is a local variable, so you store pointer to local variable which may go out of scope (in this example that's no problem, since `input` outlives main loop).

However, as you connect your signal to `input`, receiver of that signal is by default passed as first argument of callback, so you don't have to carry carry it around, so you can simplify your code to:

```
g_signal_connect(input, "changed", G_CALLBACK(change_text), NULL);
...
static void change_text(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
    const char* output = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(widget));
    printf("The text is : %s\n", output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains more things about GTK in general too